# Powershell: How to pass the XML content as a function parameter

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to write one function to update some parts of XML file, but when using the below code to do that, Powershell threw the exception

> RuntimeException： [System.Xml.XmlElement] doesn't have Save method

This is my code:

```
function removeChild ($xmlContent, $elementName) {
   .....
   $xmlContent.SelectNode(....) | ForEach-Object {
   ....}$
   return $xmlContent
}
$xmlExample = Get-Content -Path C:\Sample.xml
[xml]$xml = $xmlExample
$xml=removeChild $xml "task"
$xml.Save(“C:\Sample.xml”)
```

So how can I pass the XML content as a function parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that type `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` doesn't have a `.Save` method, which is indeed true.

However, all instances of `[System.Xml.XmlNode]` - from which `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` derives - have an `.OwnerDocument` property referencing the enclosing XML *document*, an instance of `[System.Xml.XmlDocument]` (a.k.a. `[xml]`, which too derives from `[System.Xml.XmlNode]`), and it is the latter that *does* have a `.Save` method.

Therefore, assuming that `$xml` contains an `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` instance:

```
$xml.OwnerDocument.Save(“C:\Sample.xml”)
```

However, that is *not* consistent with the code in your question, which would *not* permit an `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` to be assigned to the `[xml]`-type-constrained variable `$xml`.

Also, if the intent of your `removeNode` function is to modify an XML document *in place*, there is no need to *return* any value from that function.